# MODIS LST 8 days data to have 16 days LST?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, remote-sensing, modis

can i combinate two parameters with different Temporal Granularity , i mean can i combinate image LST MODIS 8 days with image NDVI modis 16 days??

Comment: Please edit your Question title to make it mixed case because all uppercase makes it seem like you are shouting.  While you are doing that I recommend that you revise your Question with more detail and attention to your tags because I think you would want a `modis` tag but there is no other indication that you might be using ArcGIS for Desktop than the `arcgis-10.2` tag.

Comment: thanks for answers , i'm just new here so sorry for not askng wth the appropriate way , my question was about combining two modis LST image 8 days to have one LST image 16 days , because my work is to combinate taht image of LST image 16 days with another image 16 days NDVI MODIS  mean to combinate two parameters with the sameTemporal Granularity of 16 days

Comment: No problem but for framing future questions this [**help page**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/asking) may be useful.

Comment: ok Sir PolyGeo.

Comment: For this Question to be re-opened I suspect that you will need to perform a much larger edit to revise it so that what you are asking is much clearer to potential answerers and future readers.

Comment: i'm asking about the possbility of having an image of 16days LST MODIS from two image of 8days LST MODIS because i'm going to combinate that 16 days LST MODIS with another paramater like NDVI 16days MODIS  so i  need the same temporal granituly

Comment: Please edit your Question (using the button beneath it) to include any additional details that you think may be needed in order to attract potential answerers to do so.  The speed with which Questions are Answer-ed is usually proportional to the effort and clarity with which they asked **in the body of the Question**.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this in any reliable fashion. The reason is that every MODIS product (like LST) is created from a number of observations (basically, the MOD01 radiance product) and you do not know how that is done. The MOD11A2/MYD11A2 products do not give you the number of observations that go into each product, nor the extremes.

But if you really want to do it, it is very simply done by adding up the two images and dividing by 2 to get you the average temperature over the 16 days. Not a very solid plan though. At the very least you should check the QC_day/QC_night flags and only produce the average temperature for those pixels where the lower two bits in QC_day/QC_night are 00 or 01 in both source products.